# Why this PHP class is not working to send commands using the RCON protocol?

Tags: php

I have no idea why this PHP class is not working to send commands to my game server using the RCON protocol and retrieve the response back with the `getResponse()` method. The `connect()` method returns `bool` `false` and the server is online and the credentials are right.

[Class](https://github.com/thedudeguy/PHP-Minecraft-Rcon)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try setting query-enable to true in your server config.

Comment: It is, @Adriani6.